# Как сделать залипание на секциях во время прокрутки?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать эффект остановки прокрутки, аналогичный тому, что применён на [сайте](https://www.apple.com/apple-vision-pro/) (или на других у apple) ? И как он называется?

Сайт листается, но видео на фоне во время прокрутки никак не изменяется. так же после этой секции:   [image: введите сюда описание изображения] сайт начинает ненадолго залипать на следующих секциях

Comment: Гуглите `scroll-driven animations`.